# how to make an auto post tool for asp site using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post

I need to make an online automatic post tool using ASP.NET C# to post items (using post or get) to ASP (VB script) webstore sites, for example how to capture the post data and how to reproduce it using ASP.NET C#.

need to know how to upload post and get variables also with cookies

looking for instructions, tutorials, documents, article, or even books

Thanks alot

Comment: are you asking how to develop a spam-bot?

Answer (score 0):

To get post variables in asp.net look at the class
`System.Web.HttpRequest` see property `Form`.

To send post or get variables to a asp(vbscript) web app look at class
`System.Net.WebClient` see method `UploadValues`.

Comment: @user639478 You need to fix your question then because you wrote "I need to make an online automatic post tool using ASP.NET C# to post items (using post or get) to ASP (VB script) webstore sites" Which can only be interpreted that you are writing something in C# to send data to something that already exists in asp-vb.

Comment: I dont understand, I want to send the data automatically from asp.net site, capture the data can be manually now until I know which variables to pass and use from within code

Comment: I need to upload cookies too.